# When to change quick release springs

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, long-distance, preventative-maintenance

The wife and I are newer to longer distance riding and have been learning along the way.  While this might mean different things to different people, we are training for an Ironman and will do a half distance this year as well.

One thing we are learning about is the various components that wear out when you ride a significant amount each year, like chains.  As those in the know it is important to change your chain on time as otherwise it can "ruin" your rear sprocket (a more costly fix).

So the wifey insisted her springs that go on her axle skewer "look nasty" and she ordered some off of Amazon.

Is this a thing?  Do they need to be replaced?  How often?

Comment: Presumably you're referring to the two coil springs around a QR, that function to center the QR across the hub to aid and speed Quick Changes ?

Comment: The only time a replacement is needed is when one of them gets lost, otherwise never!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those springs help center the quick-release skewer on the hub. They're a convenience--they make it faster to re-insert the wheel on the frame--but they are not necessary at all.

Which means that replacing them is not necessary for any mechanical purpose, as they can be removed entirely. If she wants them replaced for aesthetics, cleaning them may be sufficient, and replacing them doesn't hurt.

Comment: Also make sure they're one-per-side, and with the tip of the cone pointed toward the wheel's hub on both sides.

Comment: Actually, the springs are not needed for the correct functioning of the quick release. They only serve to facilitate the installation of the wheel.